# JQuery Find Performance

Tags: jquery, performance

I am finding that this:

```
var $colSelect = $('#stuff').find('.things');
$($colSelect).find('img, input, select').addClass("foo");
```

is slower then this:

```
var $colSelect = $('#stuff').find('.things');
$($colSelect).find('img').addClass("foo");                       
$($colSelect).find('input').addClass("foo");                 
$($colSelect).find('select').addClass("foo");
```

Can anyone help me understand why that is the case? In specific I am noticing the performance increase in IE8.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that for the first selector, jQuery must parse the selector, call JavaScript's `getElementsByTagName` for each and join the results (maybe even ordering them in the order of their position in the DOM).

The second case has straight-forward calls to JavaScript's `getElementsByTagName`, with no other operations necessary.

This page compares performances: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-problems

Comment: That could be it. Though I am still surprised. In my case it takes about 800ms for the first and 60ms for the second case, so I really want to understand, as that is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2: Modified to reflect the grid like nature of what you have.  Here's my findings with jQuery 1.7.1 (one is your top code, two is your bottom code).  I took only the top 5 slowest things because everything else didn't matter.

[image: Results compareing the two algorithms]

As you can see, the reason that one is probably slower than the other is **due to the function sortOrder (minified as U) and/or Array.sort. Both of these don't even show up in Two. The issue definately is with having to go back and sort the results.** makeArray (minified as s above) seems to take less time in 1, but that doesn't offset the sorting that has to be done.

Update: [I created a jsFiddle to play around with it](http://jsfiddle.net/CyqJS/), and I'm not seeing a noticeable difference in IE8 between the two methods.  Perhaps more context is needed into what this page looks like / what styles are being applied.  It may have something to do with the browser rendering which is causing your code to act differently.

IE8 has a built in profiler.

1. Go to the Developer Tools (F12)
2. Click the "Profile" tab
3. Click the "Start" button
4. Do the JavaScript work taht you need done
5. Click stop and analyze the findings. Look for things that are slow. Rework them.
6. Repeat

Tips for making your javascript better. Try not to call $($colSelect) all of the time. Save it to a variable like so.

```
var $colSelect = $($('#stuff').find('.things'));
```

Comment: You aren't in the 2nd example.

Comment: So if $colSelect is a jQuery object and I do
    $($colSelect)
it would re-search the dom? Rather I should do
    $colSelect.find(......

Comment: @user1088165 yes, you don't need to wrap it again. It won't actually re-search the dom, it's just unnecessary

Comment: I made a jsFiddle (above) and I'm not seeing big issues with my copy of IE8 with that code. Could you provide maybe more information on your html/css?

Comment: It's an editable custom made grid, about 30 rows with a few editable (5) fields(inputs) and 2 large selects per row (like 300 options.) The class being added has no style yet, it is used as a selector later on.

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the detailed analysis. That makes sense. I guess I need to think carefully on when sorting might be an issue for performance. In this case I'll need to separate the finds. Good to know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in 2nd case, the DOM subtree under $colSelect will be traversed thrice. Thats why it will be slow.

Comment: Hi Nakul, But thats the weird part, in IE i am seeing the 2nd case be faster. I am using DynaTrace to see performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#stuff .things')
    .find('img').addClass("foo").end() // .end() returns to '#stuff .things'
    .find('input').addClass("foo").end()
    .find('select').addClass("foo");
```